# First column of csv file as document number in calculating Document-Term matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, machine-learning, tf-idf

My `data.csv` file contains the following:

```
id,name
143,The sky is blue.
21,The sun is bright.
23,The sun in the sky is bright.
```

Now, I can read the whole file like this:

```
> file_loc <- "test.csv"
> x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = TRUE)
> x <- data.frame(lapply(x, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> require(tm)
  Loading required package: tm

> dd <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
```

The resultant matrix I am getting is:

```
> as.matrix(dtm)
                Terms
      Docs       143     blue.   bright.       sky       sun the
      1 0.3962406 0.3962406 0.0000000 0.1462406 0.0000000   0
      2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1949875 0.0000000 0.1949875   0
      3 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1169925 0.1169925 0.1169925   0
```

What I want is to make the `id` column of the `csv` file as the name of the `docs` like this:

```
                 Terms
      Docs      blue.   bright.       sky       sun the
      143 0.3962406 0.0000000 0.1462406 0.0000000   0
      21 0.0000000 0.1949875 0.0000000 0.1949875   0
      23 0.0000000 0.1169925 0.1169925 0.1169925   0
```

Can anybody guide as to how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: maybe read id as rownames? add `rownames = 1` to read.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `qdap` + `tm`:

```
library(qdap)

dat <- read.transcript(text="id,name
143,The sky is blue.
21,The sun is bright.
23,The sun in the sky is bright.", sep=",", header=TRUE)

## dat <- read.transcript("test.csv", sep=",")

dd <- df2tm_corpus(dat[, 2], dat[, 1])
library(tm)
as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf)))

##      Terms
## Docs      blue.   bright.       sky       sun the
##   143 0.5283208 0.0000000 0.1949875 0.0000000   0
##   21  0.0000000 0.1949875 0.0000000 0.1949875   0
##   23  0.0000000 0.1169925 0.1169925 0.1169925   0
```

Comment: Here, it is giving an extra row `id` and one extra column `name` which affects the whole result of the matrix values. So, I need to remove my `headings` to ignore `id` and `name` appear in my matrix and affect my results.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Missed that you supplied a header.  see my edit.

Comment: Can you give me some explanation about this line `dat[, 2], dat[, 1]`, so that I know, what I am doing.

Comment: That's just column indexing.  Saying the `text.var` is column 2 (`dat[, 2]`) and the `grouping.var` is column 1 (`dat[, 1]`).

Comment: What would `dat` values be if there were 3 coulmns (with first column being `id`, second `name`,third `address`)?